# How to type a variable when modifying its properties

Tags: typescript

I'm receiving data from my api in the form of the Category type but as soon as I get it, I'm adding two new properties: value and color to satisfy my nivo pie chart.

Unfortunately this leads me to get the following error:

```
'newExpenses' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.ts(7022)
```

I understand why I'm getting this error, but I'm not sure how to fix it, here's my code:

```
import DashboardBox from "@/components/DashboardBox";
import { useGetExpensesQuery, useGetCategoriesQuery } from "@/state/api";
import { useMemo } from "react";
import { ResponsivePie } from "@nivo/pie";
import { Cell, Pie, PieChart, ResponsiveContainer, Tooltip } from "recharts";
import { Category } from "@/types";

type Props = {};

const Row1 = (props: Props) => {
  const { data: categories, isLoading } = useGetCategoriesQuery();

  if (!categories || isLoading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>
  }
  const newExpenses = useMemo(() => {
    return (
      categories
      .map((category) => ({
        id: category.name,
        name: category.name,
        value: Number(
          category.expenses
            .reduce((previous, current) => previous + current.price, 0)
            .toFixed(2)
        ),
      }))
      .sort((a,b) => a.value - b.value)
      .map((category) => ({
        ...category,
        color: `rgba(64,224,208,${category.value/Math.pow(10, newExpenses[newExpenses.length-1].value.toString().length)})`
      }))
    );
  }, [categories]);

  return (
    <>
      <DashboardBox gridArea="a">
      <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
        <PieChart width={400} height={400}>
          <Pie isAnimationActive={true} paddingAngle={5} innerRadius={60}     outerRadius={80} label data={newExpenses} dataKey="value" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="#12efc8" >

            {newExpenses && newExpenses.map((entry, index) => (
              <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill={entry.color} />
            ))} 
          </Pie>
          {/* <Pie data={data02} dataKey="value" cx="50%" cy="50%" innerRadius={70} outerRadius={90} fill="#82ca9d" label /> */}
          <Tooltip />
        </PieChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
      </DashboardBox>
    </>
  );
};

export default Row1;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try `newExpenses[newExpenses.length-1].value.toString().length as number` as it's where it cycles

Comment: Please consider providing a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing without other, unrelated problems. Your code currently references a lot of third-party code, some of which is presumably local to your environment.  That means it's not a complete example (if we have no access to your local code) and is unlikely to be minimal (surely not all those third-party libraries are germane to the issue).  If you can make it easier for us to work on it, it will be more likely you'll get a useful answer.  Good luck!